# when trying to install react through my terminal I keep getting this message

Tags: npm, npm-install

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'myapp@0.0.0-1',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '0.8.x' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v18.15.0', npm: '9.5.0' }
```

How can I resolve this problem .